# Telegram, getting all emoji from sticker pack

Tags: telegram, emoji

**Situation**

I'm writing a Telegram bot. 
I need to know how many emoji(stickers) in the pack.

**What found**

In the telegram [bot api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sticker) found, that we can get only emoji (and `file_id`) for sticker.

To discover a sticker's `file_id`:

1. Send the sticker from Telegram App to bot.
2. Use the bot's `getUpdates` method to receive the sticker. Receive sticker's `file_id` in the message.

I.e., it turns out you must send all stickers to bot manualy.

**Question**

Some sites(example: [1](https://vk.com/tstickers), [2](http://www.stickerstelegram.com)) extracting stikers preview from stiker pack url:

> https://telegram.me/addstickers/animals

Any ideas how to make it automatically?